# FusedLocationProviderAPI always returns null when trying to get current location

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

For countless hours, I have been trying to get the user's current location upon launching my app, but then every approach I have tried has returned null.

My instantiation of the GoogleApiClient takes place in "onCreate"

```js
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        FirebaseMessagingHelper.registerDevice(this, FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());

        activity = this;

        //xaxaxa

        driverMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.googleMapObject);
        driverMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        driverMapView.getMapAsync(this);

        getUserToEnableCameraUsage();

        if (googleApiClient == null)
        {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
        googleApiClient.connect();
```

Here is the code in my project (extremely similar to the code provided in the api's tutorial:

```js
@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
    {
        int LOCATION_ALLOWED = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        if (LOCATION_ALLOWED != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if (lastLocation != null)
            {
                driverGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude()), 16));
                testHelper.setDriverLatLngLocation(new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude()));

            }
        }
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest()
    {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder locationSettingsRequestBuilder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> pendingResult = LocationServices
                .SettingsApi
                .checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, locationSettingsRequestBuilder.build());

        pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult)
            {
                Status result = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                if (result.getStatusCode() == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS)
                {
                    requestingLocationUpdates = true;
                    startLocationUpdates();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gucci", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (result.getStatusCode() == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED)
                {
                    requestingLocationUpdates = false;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enable location services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (result.getStatusCode() == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE)
                {
                    requestingLocationUpdates = false;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "App cannot access settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates()
    {
        int LOCATION_ALLOWED = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        if (LOCATION_ALLOWED != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        driverGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));
        testHelper.setDriverLatLngLocation(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It's working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    protected void stopLocationUpdates()
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                googleApiClient, this);
        requestingLocationUpdates = false;
    }
```

I instantiate "createLocationRequest here:

```js
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        //Setting map starts here
        int LOCATION_ALLOWED = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        if (LOCATION_ALLOWED == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        createLocationRequest();
```

The instantiation of "createLocationRequest()" takes place before the block of code that needs it and it is null?

I have looked over multiple solutions, but they've all not helped me. I was hoping that maybe someone could help me out as this has been really bothering me and has halted the development of my app.